# How to return downloadable pdf from ajax query & mpdf

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I'm generating pdf file with mpdf and ajax query.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'genPDF.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { Content, pdfContent },
    success: function(response) {

    }
)};
```

genPDF.php

```
$result = $_POST['Content'];

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($result);

$destPDF = $mpdf->Output('doc.pdf');
```

It works ok, but the file is saved on server. I need to redirect it to page with pdf creation button (file to download).
How to do that?

Comment: means after creating pdf via ajax you need to redirect to created PDF view right??

Comment: yeah, exactly :)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209897/using-ajax-and-jquery-to-create-pdf-using-fpdf

Comment: If I use `echo 'doc.pdf';` at the end of genPDF.php and `window.location = response` in success block on ajax, I can open that pdf in the same window. I would like to save it directly, not to open. Is it possible to pipe it somehow without saving pdf on server?

Comment: where u want to save??

Comment: Save by webbrowser - not to server