# Ajax download fpdf in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Expected requirement - when user clicks button ajax will be call to controller where pdf will generate and   generated pdf will gets downloaded on user's system.

Actual Scene - i able to create pdf using fpdf file and saved in folder and used force download function but nothing happend.
here's my code:

**Controller** :

```
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $this->load->library('myfpdf');
    $this->load->view('pdf/namewise_report',[]);
    $link = base_url().'uploads/pdfs/namewise.pdf';
    force_download($link, NULL);
```

**pdf/namewise_report.php (last line)**

```
    $this->myfpdf->Output('uploads/pdfs/namewise.pdf', "F");
```

is there anything to add in ajax success response

Comment: Have you looked at this? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209897/using-ajax-and-jquery-to-create-pdf-using-fpdf

Comment: Another option is to try with 'file_get_contents(the url here)' instead of AJAX;

Comment: simple, don't use ajax for this. no reason to. simple url to download controller will force download the pdf to the computer without altering the current page/causing refresh/new page opening .etc. the best way to think about ajax is like a background process worker, it is the "active" page so to speak so nothing will happen.

Comment: @Alex actually i have to use ajax because whatever parameters passing based on that pdf will generate... have to use ajax.
 i also tried file get contents and force download(name, content) but didnt work.

Comment: sorry but its just the way it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750461/xmlhttprequest-to-open-pdf-in-browser/4750685#4750685 ... that being said, there was a time when ajax never existed... so *no* you don't **have** to use ajax. find another way to pass your params.

Comment: @Alex Ok Thanks for help